# Can we use VGG19 with transferlearning and another image size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, vgg-net, image-classification

I've followed this really good example of how to use transfer learning with VGG19 and rock,paper,scissors image classification: https://github.com/Nithyashree-2022/VGG-19-for-Rock-Paper-and-Scissors-classification

I executed OK and the results were OK.That example works with 224x244 images.
Then I've tried to use my own dataset as input with 256x256 images (other type of images, not paper/rock/scissors), so, the only I've changed was the image size (and the path of them of course). I changed all references in the github code from 224 to 256, but nothing more seemed to be mandatory , but the result was... apparently no learning with validation set...

I mean:

[loss_and_accuracy_curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOE5W.png)

from epoch 1.. It seems not to learn nothing...

SO.. any ideas please??

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Vgg will work with an image size other than 224 X22 X 3. Make sure you call
tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input on your inputs before passing them to the model. vgg19.preprocess_input will convert the input images from RGB to BGR, then will zero-center each color channel with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling. To help any further I need to set the code yo used to generate your data for the model.

Comment: The code is exactly the same that appears in the github example, changing 224 to 256 (dbecause my images are 256x256), so I changed in these parts of code:

Comment: #IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224] -->   IMAGE_SIZE = [256, 256]   

for folder in os.listdir(train_path):
    [...]
    for img in os.listdir(sub_path):
        [...]
        img_arr=cv2.resize(img_arr,(256,256))  # CHANGED
         [...]        
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (256, 256), #CHANGED
                                                [...])

Comment: training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (256, 256), #CHANGED
                                                [...])
                                         
prediction = Dense(MY_N_of_CLASES, activation='softmax')(x)   #CHANGED

Comment: The original code in more "friendly" way than go to github:  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/07/step-by-step-guide-for-image-classification-on-custom-datasets/